# Converting a date column in DataTable to desired format before importing it in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am importing an excel sheet into sql server db table the table consists of 
id | data(which is actually date in mm/dd/yyyy)
I am able to import the data into database table BUT i want the data(date) column of excel sheet to be converted in to yyyy/mm/dd format before importing it into sql server. Here is my code to import excel sheet:

```
      DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
      dt7.Load(dr);

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
     using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
     {                       


     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";


     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt7);


     }
     dr.Close();
```

I have found a piece of code to convert mm/dd/yyyy into yyyy/mm/dd:

```
    string a = "12/20/2012";
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
    string st = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Label1.Text = a;
    Label2.Text = st;
```

but i have no idea how to implement it in my code. I am a complete newbie so you might have to explain with code :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have retrieve all the DataRows from the DataTable.Pick the Date column ,modify it,Put it back.

```
DataRow[]  ExcelRows;
ExcelDataTable.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows,0);

For(int i=0;i<ExcelRows.Length;i++)//i represents the row
{
     var oldDate=ExcelRows [i]["DateColumn"].ToString();
     var newDate=Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);   
     ExcelRows [i]["DateColumn"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");   
}  

 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
```

Comment: ExcelDataTable represents dt7 in my case right? i replaced it with dt7 but its all red

Comment: can not implicitly convert type'System.Data.DataRowCollection to System.Data.Datarows[]

Comment: error at  DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow();
CS0122: 'System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: my excel sheet  looks like this incase it helps : id|data(which is date)

Comment: you are wrongly declaring array mate :)  DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[ExcelDataTable.Rows.Count];

Comment: @codel there was a red line on DataRow[]  ExcelRows; so i replaced it with DataRow[] =new ExcelRows();

Comment: This is what i entered in the excel sheet : 1/15/1990

and this is what i got in database:
1/15/1990 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I think i messed up something in sqlserver i tried creating user defined datatype for just date. Although i have selected nvarchar now it still is giving me time along with date , earlier it was working fine.

Comment: probably you have your column is defined as Date Type.But my code will certainly not return the time part.its the database which is setting that

Comment: yeah i agree but even then the format is still mm/dd/yyyy which should be yyyy/mm/dd in database , its probably due to database itself i trying to find out whats wrong in database

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration

//Declare Variables - Edit these based on your particular situation
Dim sSQLTable As String = "TempTableForExcelImport"
Dim sExcelFileName As String = "myExcelFile.xls"
Dim sWorkbook As String = "[WorkbookName$]"

//Create our connection strings
Dim sExcelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(sExcelFileName) & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
Dim sSqlConnectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString


//Series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our SQL table
Dim OleDbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString)
Dim OleDbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM " & sWorkbook), OleDbConn)
OleDbConn.Open()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader()


Using bulkCopy As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(con) 
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblExcel" 

//Define ColumnMappings: source(Excel) --destination(DB Table column)   
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col1", "col1") 
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col2", "col2") 
:
:
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col2", ExcelRows [i]["DateColumn"].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) //This is for date

bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr) 

End Using 
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
OleDbConn.Close()
```